# Pythonでの単方向リストの実装

Tags: python, python3, アルゴリズム

Pythonを用いてリストを実装しようとしています。
[Linked List](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-2-inserting-a-node/) のようにして実装しています。

以下のコードの「ここ！！」とした部分ですが、なぜreturnする必要があるのでしょうか。self.headにnew_nodeが入ってif文は終わりなのではないでしょうか。
試しにreturnを消してみると、プログラムが止まらず、同関数内のwhileから抜けられていないことがわかりました。
returnは特に何も返していないと思うのですが、なぜループから抜けられなくなるか疑問です。

またprintList内のwhileですが、tempがNoneではない場合とはtemp.dataまたはtemp.nextのいずれかがNoneではないという理解で良いでしょうか。

よろしくおねがいします。

```
# Node class 
class Node: 
  
    # Function to initialize the node object 
    def __init__(self, data): 
        self.data = data  # Assign data 
        self.next = None  # Initialize next as null 
  
# Linked List class 
class LinkedList: 
    
    def __init__(self):  
        self.head = None

    def append(self, new_data): 
       new_node = Node(new_data) 

       if self.head is None: 
            self.head = new_node 
            return　　# <-----ここ！！
 
       last = self.head 
       while last.next: 
           last = last.next
 
       last.next =  new_node 


    def printList(self): 
        temp = self.head 
        while temp: 
            print(temp.data) 
            temp = temp.next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 以下のコードの「ここ！！」とした部分ですが、なぜreturnする必要があるのでしょうか。

それは2つの処理の塊が排他的な条件で(どちらかだけ)実行されるべきものだからでしょう。

`head`が`None`の時に行う処理：空の`head`に1つの`new_node`をリンクする

```
if self.head is None: 
    self.head = new_node 
    return　　<-----ここ！！
```

`head`が`None`以外の時に行う処理：リンクをたどっていって、最後に1つの`new_node`をリンクする

```
last = self.head 
while last.next: 
   last = last.next

last.next =  new_node
```

上記の`return`を削除すると、両方の処理が実行されることになり、最初の`append`が済むと`head`にリンクされたノードの`next`が`last.next =  new_node`によって自分自身を指すことになります。
その後2つ目の`append`を行おうとすると無限ループになります。

こちらの記事の方が分かりやすいかもしれませんね：
[連結リスト（Linked List）を大学生が解説してみた　by python](https://astrostory.hatenablog.com/entry/2020/02/24/070213)

それぞれの処理を`if:`と`else:`で分けています。
こちらの記事も`if:`の方に`return`が入っていますが、こちらの`return`は削除しても動作します。

---

> またprintList内のwhileですが、tempがNoneではない場合とはtemp.dataまたはtemp.nextのいずれかがNoneではないという理解で良いでしょうか。

これは違います。

`temp`が`None`ではない場合とは`head`または`temp.next`が`None`ではないということです。
`temp.data`は何であっても構いません。

---

**コメント対応追記：**

「while文がtemp.nextのみを見る」のは、このメソッドが「リンクの末尾に指定された値を持つノードを追加する」だけのものだからです。
この時必要なのは、「next」の値だけです。

これが例えば「オブジェクトが合計値や平均値という属性を持って」いて、「ノードを追加すると自動的にそれらを計算しなおす」といった機能を持っているならば、ノード追加の処理中にそれぞれのノードの「data」を読み取って何かの処理を行うステップが追加されます。

---

**コメント対応追記その２：**

「while temp:」のところで判断の元になっているのは、`temp`が`False`で無い(プログラム上は`True`と同じ扱いである`Node`クラスインスタンスのアドレスか、または`False`と同じ扱いである`None`)かどうかであって、その中身が何でどうなっているか、については関係ありません。

「while temp:」の時点では`temp`が`False`では無い何かの数値/文字列/オブジェクトであってもループは実行されるでしょう。
もちろん、`Node`クラスインスタンスのアドレスでなければ、その下のwhileループ内の処理でエラーになって終了しますが。

Comment: ありがとうございました。前半は理解できました。後半の質問で、
「temp.dataは何であっても構いません」
とのことだったのですが、while文はなぜtemp.nextのみを見るのでしょうか。

Comment: コメントに対応していただきありがとうございます。tempにはdata,nextの２つ変数を持っていると思うのですが、「while temp:」のところでwhileはtempのdataとnextの両方からTrueまたはFalseを判断しているのでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございました。丁寧に回答していただき、理解できました。